# Understanding callbacks with parameters

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I'm a little bit confused on the following code below. The part that I don't understand is how does the result parameter equal to the result of the `callback(x+y)`. Can someone explain this and perhaps the order of steps that this executes in?

```
function add(x,y, callback){
  callback(x+y)
}

add(3,4, function(result){
  console.log(result) //logs out 7
})
```

I know that 3+4 is 7, but I don't specifically understand how the result parameter gets this 7 value.

Comment: It's a function parameter just like any other function parameter.  It's no different from passing `3` as `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, and once you understand this, it's going to open a lot of doors in Javascript.

Let's look at what happens without a callback:

```
function add(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

add(1, 2) // returns 3
```

When you `return x + y`, that's what you get back from the function.

Now let's introduce a new function, but not as a callback.

```
function add(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

function logResult(result) {
  console.log(result)
}

var result = add(1, 2) // 3
logResult(result) // outputs "3"
```

As you see, we call `add`, get the result, and then pass it into `logResult`, which outputs it to the console.

If we pass `logResult` as a function in the third argument of `add`, and then we call it inside `add` with the `result`, it's effectively the same thing!

```
function add(x, y, callback) {
  var result = x + y;

  // we're calling the function that gets passed in
  // which is `logResult`
  callback(result)
}

function logResult(result) {
  console.log(result)
}

add(x, y, logResult) // outputs "3"
```

And now we circle back to your example, which reduces everything to the minimal code needed:

```
function add(x, y, cb) {
  cb(x + y);
}

add(1, 2, function (result) {
  console.log(result)
}); // outputs "3"
```

In JS you can pass functions into other functions. The function that receives another function as an argument can call it. That's what you have here. You can also reduce this even further:

```
function add(x, y, cb) {
  cb(x + y)
}

add(1, 2, console.log) // outputs "3"
add(1, 2, console.error) // outputs "3" in error format
```

Comment: And when you tell him a function can return a function, his head asplode! :)

Comment: thank you for the great explanation. now i know more!

Answer (score 0):

The `add` function is called with these arguments:

```
x = 3
y = 4
callback = function(result) { console.log(result) }
```

That function sums `x+y`. That produces `7`.

Then it calls the `callback` function with this argument:

```
result = 7
```

That function logs `7` in the console

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
function add(x,y, callback){
  callback(x+y)
}

add(3,4, function(result){
  console.log(result) //logs out 7
})
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
function add(x,y, callback){
  callback(x+y);
}

function output(result){
  console.log(result);
}

add(3,4, output);
```

So the function add takes 3 parameters, when calling `add(3,4,output)`,

1. the parameter `x` is assigned the value `3`
2. the parameter `y` is assigned the value `4`
3. the parameter `callback` is assigned a pointer to the function `output`

Since `callback` in the call above is a pointer to the function `output`, when you do `callback(x+y)` you're actually calling `output(3+4)`.

It's nothing special. It's just a result of javascript treating functions as first class values.